# Propagating sessions via url

Tags: php

In php, according to the manual : "A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL."

**When and why** should i prefer passing the sessions through the url rather than a cookie?

Comment: If you are afraid that users don't transmit cookie

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that your session token may be sent to a different domain via the referrer, but this could be mitigated by checking the origin IP address. Beside this, cookies are sent in HTTP headers, the URL ends up in the request line. There's no real difference regarding security, because HTTPS encrypts both. But the request URL may be written in a log file and this is a (minor obviously) risk.

Cookies are the default handler to pass session tokens, but you can fallback to a param in the query string when they are disabled on the client side.

Comment: your last sentence suggests that i should implement sessions via **both** cookies and url in my application and use the latter approach as a backup if user has disabled cookies..right?

Comment: Really I suggest using only cookies :) it's not easy to implement the URL version, there are security implications you must watch against, and nobody really disables cookies (or JavaScript btw)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question,

**Cookies can be modified (um yea hacked) , but sessions can't.**

Comment: do you mean that passing sessions via url is more secure than the cookie approach?

Comment: This really doesn't mean anything. Cookies are user input from the service perspective. When the session token is passed via a cookie, if you pass the wrong text you are not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

sessions in url:

1. It is a rather large amount of work to carry through session ids in
   the urls.
2. It is a small amount of work to fix the security issues resulting from cookies.
3. It just looks uglier to have every url have the ending ?session_id=foobar23454364634

sessions in cookies:

1. It is almost no amount of work to carry a session_id with cookies.
2. It is a medium amount of work to be aware of the security issues result from sessino cookies (XSRF).
3. Urls are not modified.

You can either choose your way ot implement both and let the user choose.